# Calculating differences between many images

Tags: image, matlab, registration

My problem is one related to image registration. I have a number of images in a .tif-file, all the same size. I read those into MATLAB as a 3D-array of matrices and try to optimize the overlay of features in those images solely by rotation. I tried using imabsdiff, but resorted to just doing it like shown below. 
In short, I input a vector containing as many angles as I have images in my stack. I rotate each image in the stack by each corresponding angle. Then, I calculate the absolute differences ([image1-image2] + [image2-image1]) which is what imabsdiff does, but faster. For this, I use two loop variables and compare each individual image to the whole stack, while leaving out comparison between identical images. Cost is the sum of differences between all images.

```
for oo = 1:slidecount
    centered_stack(:,:,oo) = imrotate(centered_stack(:,:,oo),
    angle_in(oo), 'bilinear', 'crop');
end

for pp = 1:slidecount
    image1 = centered_stack(:,:,pp);
    for qq = 1:slidecount
        if qq ~= pp % only do this if comparing different images
            image2 = centered_stack(:,:,qq);
            cost_temp(qq) = sum(sum(abs(image1 - image2))) +  
            sum(sum(abs(image2 - image1))); 
        else 
            cost_temp(qq) = 0;
        end
        cost_temp = sum(cost_temp);    
    end
    cost(pp) = cost_temp;
end

cost = sum(cost);
```

This then serves as a cost value for an optimization procedure. Can someone please tell me if there is a faster, maybe vectorized way to do this or something conceptually completely different? This approach gets very time consuming with many images. FFT based registration maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Just a question: when you rotate and crop, don't you end up with black borders or otherwise smaller sized images? If so - this seems to artificially increase the absolute error. What is the problem that you're trying to solve? Finding the correct rotation angles? Also, which MATLAB version are you using? Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm trying to find the right rotation angles to get the maximal overlay between features in the images. I do have the image processing toolbox, but things like imabsdiff just take more time. The MATLAB version is 2016b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you compare each pair of images twice:

1. image_1 to image_2 (pp == 1, qq == 2)
2. image_2 to image_1 (pp == 2, qq == 1)

Is this intended? If you make second loop look like this:

```
for qq = (pp+1):slidecount
```

you will reduce the computation by the factor of 2. Also your condition for checking `qq ~= pp` will not be needed anymore.

Comment: Hi pkic, thanks for the reply. You are correct, it does look like I am comparing more images than I need to. Thanks for catching that, I will try your suggestion!

Comment: Hi @drummy_1, thanks for accepting my answer. I am having another doubt about your code. My understending of mathematics tells me that `abs(image1 - image2)` is exactly the same as `abs(image2-image1)`. Is there any particular reason that you do this operation twice? The only reason is see those operations would be different is because you have the overflow issue (e.g. your images are of uint8 type: uint8(5) - uint8(10) = 0 while uint8(10) - uint8(5) = 5). If this is your issue I suggest you change the format of your images because the code dosen't really do what you want.

Comment: Hi pkic, you are right, this is a problem of using uint8. However, as it is very important these images are tampered with as little as possible, we keep them like that. And in that case, taking abs(image1-image2) gives a different value than abs(image2-image1). And maybe surprisingly the code works perfectly doing that! Thank you!